# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer

When I goto my site I get this error...

```
Error   101 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. C:\mlui\csharp\WebAdmin_solution\WebAdmin\web.config    209
```

which is this line of code:

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012, do I need to download something and add it to the VS 2012 folder?

Answer (score 6):

If you're actually using the Reporting Services, try to install the Reporting Services redistributable on the server you deploy your web site to or include the required assemblies with your web application.

Comment: Do you have a link where I can download it?

Comment: How would I include the required assembiles to my web application?

Comment: It should be on your development machine already, but you can try this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3841

Comment: Well, there must be a reference to the assemblies in your project - can you set the "Local copy" property to `true` in the reference's properties? Then the DLLs should be copied to the output folder. At least this is the case for desktop projects...

Answer (score 4):

Right Click on the Project and open and go to Manage NuGet Package

Under browse tap search for **Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms**

select Microsoft.ReportView.Webforms

[image]

and click install.

- so it will take care of respective dependency and so on,

Answer (score 3):

Look at your folder instalation, what version have the folder ReportViewer.
And put  Version=X.0.0.0 where X means the version of your instalation.

In my case, I have

[image: Instalation Folders]

But only inside 10.0 I have the ReportViewer

[image: ReportViewer Folder]

And my web.xml is like this

```
<assemblies>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
    <buildProviders>
                <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            </buildProviders>
```

Comment: thanks guys.. i've got the idea that maybe there is no installed reportviewer in that server.. so i download a separate installer for reportviewer for vs2010.. and it works!!

Answer (score 2):

try to update it with latest assembly of version 10.0 by add reference to your project and build it again after adding assembly file will looks something like below

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

Answer (score -1):

Just Search Microsoft report viewer in internet you will get exe file , install it, Issue will resolved